# Optimizing Nitrous.io Resources

Tags: nitrousio

I Have been using Nitrous.io IDE and I have almost consumed most of the free resource provided at the beginning as well as the ones we earn through nitrous completing goals. How can i optimize my resources?

I don't know what consumes 1000 mb of storage space, please let me know how to clear unwanted files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see which specific folders are using up disk space, you can run the following command in your console:

View overall disk usage:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h ~/ | sort -g -r
```

If you ran out of space due to installing packages from Autoparts then you could delete the archives found in ~/.parts/archives. Else, you may need to uninstall other modules/gems if those folders appear to take up the majority of space.

Most of the disk space used from the initial creation is related to the Ruby/Rails or which ever template you chose, so you will want to increase the box's disk space past 1GB if [you have extra N2O](https://www.nitrous.io/app#/n2o/bonus). You can click 'Settings' on the boxes page in order to [increase the disk space](http://help.nitrous.io/box-settings/).